# Importar descrição de outra tabela

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Olá pessoal eu tenho o seguinte código:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS categorias_total, v_lctos_despesa.id_categorias
FROM 'v_lctos_despesa'
INNER JOIN categorias ON (v_lctos_despesa.id_categorias = categorias.id_tipo)
GROUP BY v_lctos_despesa.id_categorias
```

porém o resultado dele não está correto, gostaria que ele trouxesse a descrição da categoria e não a id:

> ```
> categoria1 = 10
> categoria2 = 15
> ```

ele está trazendo:

> ```
> 1 = 10
> 2 = 15
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Não seria o caso apenas você alterar o campo de retorno?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS categorias_total, v_lctos_despesa.desc_categorias --valida o nome do campo
FROM 'v_lctos_despesa'
INNER JOIN categorias ON (v_lctos_despesa.id_categorias = categorias.id_tipo)
GROUP BY v_lctos_despesa.desc_categorias
```

obs: repare que fazendo isso, você precisa alterar também o campo do `group by`, que deve ser igual ao trazido no *select*.